# Clicking on question title with LaTeX equation sometimes doesn't open the question

Tags: bug, latex

Clicking on question title containing LaTeX equation sometimes doesn't open the question. Example:

[image]

Tested on Windows 7, Chrome 53.

Comment: It looks like it's trying to throw itself into some sort of edit mode.

Comment: Jagged little pixel